# Spelling dictionary corrupted

Tags: bugs, notebooks, editing

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and fixed in 9.0.1**

---

I have a problem with the Check Spelling in Mathematica, that I quite don't understand:

If I try to use the Check Spelling on any notebook, the check just stop before the first word and in the field "**Reason for stopping:**" is written: "*The spelling dictionary file Mathematica.rws could not be loaded. The file may be corrupted.*"

I found nothing about this on the Internet, but after a research on my computer I found that this file is at "*/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/SpellingDictionaries/English/Mathematica.rws*" (I'm on Linux)

There is also another directory called *SpellingDictionaries* at *~/.Mathematica/SystemFiles/SpellingDictionaries*, but it is empty.

I tried by copying the content of the first directory in the second, but it doesn't work.

I also tried to use another file *Mathematica.rws* that I found in */WINDOWS/Program Files/Wolfram Research/Mathematica/8.0/SystemFiles/SpellingDictionaries* on another computer (under Windows) that had Mathematica V8 (with which the check spelling worked). I doesn't work either.

Can anyone help me ? I would really like to be able to use Mathematica to write my report.

Comment: Could you try [restoring to factory settings](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2008/Feb/msg00035.html) and let us know if it helped?

Comment: Doesn't worked... I'll try to update to 9.0.1

Comment: user, you don't need the "[Solved]" tag in the title; that's what the Accept feature is for, which I see you already know how to use (thanks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not recall all the details, but I belive this was a bug on some operating systems (e.g. Linux x86) for`$Version` 9.0 `$ReleaseNumber` 0. It should be fixed if you upgrade to 9.0.1. Let me know if that fixes your problem.

Comment: The update to 9.0.1 solved the problem.   Thanks!